# Which font is used for the title logo of Unix & Linux website?

Tags: discussion, design

Which font is use for the title logo of our website? The closes I found is Liberation Serif but it is not exactly the same font used for logo

Answer (score 7):

According to the [myfont.com](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/results?ch%5B0%5D=U&ch%5B1%5D=N&ch%5B2%5D=I&ch%5B3%5D=X&ch%5B4%5D=%26&ch%5B5%5D=L&ch%5B6%5D=I&ch%5B7%5D=N&ch%5B8%5D=U&ch%5B9%5D=X&session=0008c46e566f790d000f23b60000754d1&x=53&y=26) font identifier, it's Georgia. And indeed, as you can see in the image below which I created in LibreOffice using the Georgia font, it does look about right:

[image: Unix & Linux logo attempt]

Comment: Except the N and the U look funny...I guess someone scaled those down in the logo to look better.  :)

Comment: @Wildcard The reason those look funny is that they’re faking (emulating, poorly) the small caps needed because Georgia doesn't have actual small caps in the font. That’s why the ELU logo was done in Caslon. I point out this deficiency [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4977/2649).